# Fail to render LATEX output using Weave

Tags: julia

I am using macOS and VScode. I find Weave.jl fail to render LATEX output.

Example code:

````
# Demo
**Everything** works fine, _except_ for LATEX elements.

I want beta in `LATEX`:
1. $\beta$
2. ``\beta``
3. $$\beta$$
4. ```math \beta ```
````

[image]

Comment: Please also include the `weave` call you are using to produce the output. And the output of `xelatex -v` on your terminal.